# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(PermissionHandler.PermissionManager, Unable to detect current Android Activity., null, null)

Tags: flutter

I have the following problem.
I'm building a flutter app which needs permission to get the location.
The app should request every permission that it needs when the app starts.
For this i use the package: [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

This is my Code which i use to try getting my idea:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
  requestPermissions();
}
```

```
void requestPermissions() async {
  bool reqSuc = false;
  List<Permission> permissions = [
    Permission.location,
  ];


  for (Permission permission in permissions) {
    if (await permission.isGranted) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        logger.i("Permission: $permission already granted");
      }
      reqSuc = true;
      continue;
    } else if (await permission.isDenied) {
      PermissionStatus permissionsStatus = await permission.request();
      if (permissionsStatus.isGranted) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          logger.i("Permission: $permission already granted");
        }
        reqSuc = true;
      } else if (permissionsStatus.isPermanentlyDenied) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          logger.i("Permission: $permission is permanently denied");
        }
        reqSuc = false;
      }
    }
  }
  if (reqSuc == false) {
    openAppSettings();
  }
```

Also I put following permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

But if I try to run this code im getting the Exception which i meantioned in the title:

`[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(PermissionHandler.PermissionManager, Unable to detect current Android Activity., null, null)`

Is there a way to fix this excpetion or another way to request the permissions at the start of the app?

Edit: Is there a way to ensure that the .MainActivity is loaded before requsting the permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the fix was just to use a FutureBuilder:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: requestPermissions(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
          darkTheme: AppTheme.darkTheme,
          themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
          home: const NavigationPage(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  requestPermissions();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

**RUN:**

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Comment: still getting the same error :/

Comment: go pubspec change version to any eg: permission_handler: any  and then delete the pubspec.lock file. Then run flutter clean flutter pub get and then flutter run ,

Comment: Sadly im still getting the error after this

Comment: Change the compileSdkVersion to 30 or 31

Comment: This also can not work because the package requires a compileSdkVersion 33

Answer (score 0):

add this line of code to your main.dart

**await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.location]);**

Replace location with the permission you are requesting.

Make sure that the Flutter project is properly linked to the Android project. You can do this by running the following command in your project directory:

**flutter clean && flutter pub get && flutter run**

Comment: I dont even have a class which is called PermissionHandler() so i can just not use it because it is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```dart
  Future<void> checkLocation() async {
    Location location = Location();
    bool? serviceEnabled;
    PermissionStatus? permissionGranted;
    serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
    }

    permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
    }
  }
```

Run thefunction in your main app

```dart
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  checkLocation();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```